# Find $n$ if $I$ attains its minimum value

Tags: calculus

> Given $$I=\int_{n}^{n^2}\frac{1}{x+\sqrt{x}}dx$$
>
> Find $n$ if $I$ attains its minimum value.

My attempt,

I integrated the definite integral and I got $2\ln(n+1)-2\ln(\sqrt{n}+1)$. How do I proceed?

Comment: You have $I(n)=2\ln(n+1)-2\ln(\sqrt{n}+1)$ so it's just like any other optimization problem?

Comment: Is $n$ a general real number, or just a positive integer? Because the answer is rather silly unless $0<n<1$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Why? https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bzgayfjvgf

Comment: @Shuri2060 For the obvious reason that, if the minimum is taken over $n\ge1$, the answer is just that the integrand is strictly positive and $I(1)=0$.

Comment: And what's wrong with that?

Comment: @Shuri2060 It's just dumb. One takes the time to write the whole set-up of an exercise just to have the answer being an uninteresting trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

Let $$f (t)=\frac {1}{t+\sqrt {t}} $$
and
 $$F (x)=\int_x^{x^2} f (t)dt.$$

then

$$F'(x)=2xf (x^2)-f (x) $$

solve for $n $ the equation $$F'(n)=0$$

which can be written as

$$\frac {2}{n+1}=\frac {1}{n+\sqrt {n}} $$

Comment: except that $n$ seems to be an integer and your last equation has no integer solution. Usually taking the derivative to find the minimum of an integer sequence is not the best approach

Comment: @fonfonx:  OP didn't say it was an integer, though it often is.  Even so, taking it as real and taking the derivative is often effective.  If the solution is smooth enough you can just check the integers on each side of the maximum.

Comment: I agree on the part "check the integers on each side", it is true that the derivative will get an interesting understanding of the function, but not directly the solution (if $n$ is really an integer which I assumed, even though it was not explicitly specified by OP)

Answer (score 1):

Write it as 
$$2\ln\left(\frac{n+1}{\sqrt{n}+1}\right)$$
and since $\ln(x)$ is increasing, you want to minimize the argument of the logarithm.
$$\frac{d}{dn}\frac{n+1}{\sqrt n+1}=\frac{n+2\sqrt n -1}{2\sqrt n(\sqrt n+1)^2}=0\iff n+2\sqrt n-1=0\iff(\sqrt n+1)^2=2$$
$$\sqrt n+1=\pm\sqrt{2}\implies \sqrt n =\sqrt 2-1\iff n=(\sqrt 2-1)^2=3-2\sqrt 2$$

Comment: This is a local minimum, not maximum

Answer (score 1):

You derive $f(n)=2\ln(n+1)-2\ln(\sqrt{n}+1)$ wrt $n$

you get $f'(n)=\dfrac{2}{n+1}-\dfrac{1}{\left(\sqrt{n}+1\right) \sqrt{n}}$

Solve $f'(n)=0\to n+2 \sqrt{n}-1=0$

Set $\sqrt n=t$ and solve $t^2+2t-1=0\to  t=\sqrt{2}-1$

$n=t^2=3-2 \sqrt{2}$ for which the integral is $I=\log \left(12-8 \sqrt{2}\right)$

Comment: Does that mean the answer is wrong? @RossMillikan

Comment: @Mathxx You wanted a minimum, didn't you? So my answer is right as well as the answer of the other poster

Comment: Misread the question.  This is right